# How to check for delimiter used as "^" in a unicode file in Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

I have file of type unicode, I need to get the check the file if `^` is being used as a delimiter or not using batch script

Here is example of the file content:

```
Case Id^Subcase Id^Cr Date Cust^Case Title^Contact First Name^Contact Last Name^Customer Phone Number^Contact E Mail
```

The approach i tried using is to fetch the first line of the file, store to a variable and then do a findstr on the string for `^` character it seems to be not working here.

Here is the code snippet that i tried:

```
set /p var1= < C:\corvallis\diversionpl.csv
echo %var1% |findstr /lic:"^" >nul && set "isFormat=FOUND" || set "isFormat=NOT FOUND"
echo %isFormat%
```

Are there any options from the above approach that has been tried out?

Comment: Put a sample file up for download on `Dropbox` so people can investigate this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "carets="
    for /f %%a in (
      'findstr /n /r /c:"^" data.txt ^| findstr /b /c:"1:" ^| find /c "^"'
    ) do set "carets=%%a"

    echo %carets%
    if "%carets%"=="7" ( echo FOUND ) else ( echo NOT FOUND )
```

How does it work? The first `findstr` just reads all the file, numbering the lines. The second `findstr` filters the data to only retrieve the first line. Until here, all the data flowing along the pipe is unicode. Now, `find /c` is used to converts this data to ansi, the nulls between characters into line feeds and count the number of lines containing `^`, that is, the number of separators (if found) inside the first line

But this will only work under the assumption that the file is unicode.

Why the `for` or `set /p` approach do not work? If the file is unicode (yes, relaxed usage of the term), there are two bytes per character, the "normal" one and a 0x00 (null) char. And in batch files, variables can not hold nulls. You can try to read the line, but the variable will not hold the readed data.

**edited** for a more concise way of doing it both in unicode or ansi file (this time just testing the presence of the `^` in the first line)

```
(type data.txt 2>nul|(set /p "data="&(set data|find "^">nul)))&& echo found || echo not found
```

or

```
(type data.txt 2>nul|(set /p "data="&(set data|find "^">nul)))
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo not found
) else (
    echo found
)
```

And yes, it uses `set /p`, because the `type` command will "convert" the file from unicode.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop can process contents of a file and do lots of manipulations to it ...  I'm not sure if this algorithm would work but it should atleast get you somewhere...

```
 @echo off

 For /f "tokens=*" %%a in (filename.extension) do (

 Echo "%%a" ¦ find "^^"

      )

 Pause
```

Comment: The tokens * would parss each word in every possible line piping  standard output to find and would print out every line containing the ^ character

Comment: Hi Mordecai,
thank for your quick response I tried with posted code it does not display out any results at all

Comment: My pgonephone keyboard doesn't have a vertical bar ... Replace ¦ with pipe symbol

Comment: Also add a double ^ to escape the original meaning of the ^ symbol

Comment: On my way to work .. if that still doesn't work ..I will test It there and probably come up with a workaround

Comment: nope findstr too does not work..the problem is the file is in unicode format,if we get the first line of the file with the delimiters to a string variable and then do find will that work out...if so how do i fetch the first line with the delimiters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
         @echo off

         Set string=<%~1

         Echo %string% ¦ find "^^"

         Pause
```

Drag the file onto the batch file so it becomes the first argument and set will declare an instance variable of it .... Long shot .. hope it helps

Comment: C:\corvallis>set /p var1=   0<C:\corvallis\diversionpl.csv

C:\corvallis>echo ÿþC   | find "^"
I get this from the command prompt....when i executed the script...the first line is not displayed correctly...

Comment: C:\corvallis>set /p var1=   0<C:\corvallis\diversionpl.csv

C:\corvallis>echo ÿþC   | find "^"

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` with the field separator set to `^` which you will need to escape.

```
awk -F \^ '{ print NF; n+=1 }; END { print n }' temp.txt
```

Will print the number of fields on each line followed by the number of lines - I am sure that you could find a better usage but it gives you a starting point.